# What is the equivalent code in C# for RequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE.NO_TITLE)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, fullscreen

I wonder how to write this code in C#

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can code like this:

```
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```

Usually the API are the same as it in Java.